# Different outcomes using include? and between? for same date range Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Why do I get different outcomes in these two queries?

**Query 1 = false** (creating array of shift IDs then checking if shift ID is in array):

```
shifts = Shift.where('date_time BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.zone.now - 3.hours, Time.zone.now + 24.hours).pluck(:id)

shifts.include?(16923) # false
```

**Query 2 = true** (checking if shift date_time is between a time range):

```
Shift.find(16923).date_time.between?(Time.zone.now - 3.hours, Time.zone.now + 24.hours) # true
```

The attribute `date_time` is a string, can that have anything to do with it?

At the time of writing, here are the current results:

`Shift.find(16923).date_time` = `"2018-09-01T07:45:00+00:00"`

`Time.zone.now - 3.hours` = `Fri, 31 Aug 2018 13:34:07 BST +01:00`

`Time.zone.now + 24.hours` = `Sat, 01 Sep 2018 16:35:22 BST +01:00`

Looks to me that it's between those two ranges, so why is it not included in the first array?

Comment: what does the query being generated look like? `Shift.where('date_time BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.zone.now - 3.hours, Time.zone.now + 24.hours).to_sql` ?

Comment: "SELECT \"shifts\".* FROM \"shifts\" WHERE (date_time BETWEEN '2018-08-31 15:05:13.583913' AND '2018-09-01 18:05:13.590677')"

Comment: that looks right... perhaps the column for id is a strange type (e.g. string)? you might have better luck with something like: `shift = Shift.where('date_time BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.zone.now - 3.hours, Time.zone.now + 24.hours).find_by(:id => 16923)`  have you manually confirmed that the id is present when doing something like: `puts Shift.where('date_time BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.zone.now - 3.hours, Time.zone.now + 24.hours).pluck(:id).sort`?

Comment: The ID is not in the list that gets rendered by `Shift.where('date_time BETWEEN ? AND ?', Time.zone.now - 3.hours, Time.zone.now + 24.hours).pluck(:id)`, that's what I'm struggling with...I don't understand why one query has a different outcome when both use seemingly the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`date_time` is a String or a DateTime object? that may be the problem.

Because both String and Datetime objects accept a `between?` method, both inherited at the end from Comparable https://apidock.com/ruby/Comparable/between%3F

A String will be compared alfabethically

```
'11'.between?('0','2') # => true
```

A DateTime object will call `between?` on a Time objects which is represented as an integer and it's compared ordinally

```
11.between?(0,2) # => false
```

If `date_time` is a String, I'd suggest to change it to a DATETIME column type, it makes more sense semantically. If you can't change it, you can add a custom getter to return a DateTime object parsing the string.

```
def date_time
  DateTime.parse(self[:date_time])
end
```

I'm not that familliar with SQL operators and it's optimizations, but I'm guessing it is comparring both ordinally, that's would explain why the query works and not the `between?` method. Still I can't confirm this, I'm just guessing (maybe it even depends on the implementation and the table engine, I don't know).